# Parse json string to search for a particular key from Phoenix table

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I am trying to access a table created through Phoenix from Hbase. The value for a REQUEST column is JSON string and I want to write a phoenix query to search for a particular key e.g. "merchant" from it and as a result want its distinct value back and total count.

How can I do this using Phoenix query?

```
ColumnName                        Value

KEY                          ABC-123
CODE                         123
REQUEST                      {"notification":{"source":"ABC","device":"Android"},"template":{"job":"Real","merchant":"ABC"}}
```

Expected Output:
merchant  count(*)
ABC        1